# Loading two videos at a time via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application running in rails 3.1 where a page displays embedded videos.  I only want to show two at once and have an AJAX option to load more videos without refreshing the page.  More or less how regular commenting systems work e.g. youtube's options to view the next comments and view the previous comments.

I'm having difficulty getting the proper videos to display when the partial they're placed in is loaded via AJAX.  I guess the general question this boils down to is how to pass parameters to partials via AJAX.  I've tried a variety of methods but can't seem to get it to work.

_videos

```
<% for video in @videos %>
<p> Video #1 </p>
<%= raw youtube_embed(video.video_link) %> <%# outputs regular html, youtube_embed is a module helper %>    
<% end %>
<p> testing </p>
```

next_videos.js.erb

```
$('#next_videos').replaceWith('<%=escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'videos'))%>');
```

controller method

```
def next_videos
@videos = Video.find_all_by_id('1')
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(root_path, :notice => 'Error') }
  format.js # the actual ajax call
end
end
```

I would like to show two videos at a time.  I was thinking to implement this via a counter that gets passed to the partial along with the @videos.  What's the best way of implementing something like this?  Am I going about this the wrong way?  Also, I've read conflicting arguments that you cannot GET or POST partials.  If anyone can shed some light on this it would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to implement this was using a session variable to keep track of the current videos being displayed between AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

In your videos partial you should write something like this

```
<% for video in videos %>
<p> Video #1 </p>
<%= raw youtube_embed(video.video_link) %> <%# outputs regular html, youtube_embed is a module helper %>    
<% end %>
<p> testing </p>
```

Note videos not @videos as you were passing it as local

Comment: It actually works both ways because the instance variable automatically carries over to the partial and I was assigning the variable videos to "@videos" in my javascript.  Passing the locals through the js was unnecessary, if you take that out then "@videos" is the only one that works.